# Connecting a Node JS Socket Server on Heroku to a front end client

Tags: node.js, sockets, heroku

I am having trouble getting a front end client to connect to my back end Node JS server on HEROKU. I am aware that heroku uses process.env.PORT to decide which port you can route socket traffic through, but due to the fact that my client will not be hosted on the same server I will not be able to access this ever-changing environment variable. I was wondering if there is any workaround for this problem which would let my front end client connect to my socket on Heroku without having to know the port ahead of time.

Relevent Node Code

```
var net = require('net');
var port = process.env.PORT || 9001
var mySocket;


var serverF = net.createServer(function(socket) {  
    mySocket = socket;  
    mySocket.on("connect", onConnect);  
    mySocket.on("data", onData);  
});  

function onConnect()  
{  
    console.log("Connected to Flash");  
}  
serverF.listen(port);

function onData(d)  
{

    if(d == "exit\0")  
    {  
        console.log("exit");  
        mySocket.end();  
        server.close();  
    }   
    else  
    {  
        console.log(d);
        mySocket.write(d, 'utf8'); 
    }  
}
```

I am trying to use flash as my front-end client, but I tried to simplify and wrote a basic client in node to run to isolate the problem and ran into the same issue.

This is a continuation of an ongoing problem I have that can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32601186/creating-a-socket-server-with-nodejs-on-heroku-with-flash-as-the-client

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not just "know" where it's running.   You can, however set up a central registry somewhere with the port information listed.  sort of a service registry 'lite'.

Just publish a static site somewhere with the port information, then request that static source first.   Once you've parsed the info there, you're good to go.

Or, if you have the resources, set up a reverse proxy somewhere that will always be available, and that you can use to change your dynamic back-end.